# Regex in Python: Allow double and single quotation marks

Tags: python, regex, quotation-marks

With a Python script I want to extract parameters from my Dart code (Strings).

When I have `AppLocalizations.of(context).translate("translationKey")`, I want to get `translationKey`.

The following code is working perfectly for double quotation marks ("..."), but I can't get it to work for single quotation marks ('...').

```
for line in dartFile:
    quotes = re.findall('AppLocalizations.of\(context\).translate\("([^"]*)"\)', line)
```

How can I also get `AppLocalizations.of(context).translate('translationKey')` working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you

```
for line in dartFile:
    quotes = re.findall("""AppLocalizations\.of\(context\)\.translate\([\"']([^\"']*)[\"']\)""", line)
```

You can use `"""` to write strings more freely, you can even go to the next line without using \n.